# JavaFX in Swing useability

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a desktop application written with Swing, I've incorporated a JavaFX component to my application through JFXPanel. Everything runs fine but just one time. When I close the JFrame with the JavaFX components and later try to open it again by creating new JFrame, the space with the JXPanel is empty.

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Scene scene = new Scene( mainPane );
        setScene(scene);
      }
    });
```

this is how I run the JFXPanel.

Comment: *"..by creating new JFrame.."* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call Platform.setImplicitExit(false)